# Symfony forms: does it omits a `false` `attr`?

Tags: php, forms, symfony

I want to know in `JavaScript` if a particular feature is active or not.

I have a `PHP` class that has some `has*` methods.

So, in `Twig` I do this:

```
{{ form_widget(form.plan.seo, {'attr': {'class': 'feature', 'data-already-active': store.premium.hasSeo}}) }}
```

I expect it sets `data-already-active` to `0` or to `1` depending on the feature is active or not.

But the generated HTML is this if the `has*` method returns `true`:

```
<input type="checkbox" id="form_plan_seo" name="form[plan][seo]" class="feature" data-already-active="data-already-active" value="1" checked="checked">
```

while simply omits the `data-already-active` attribute if the `has*` method returns `false`:

```
<input type="checkbox" id="form_plan_social" name="form[plan][social]" class="feature" value="1">
```

More, has you can see, the value of the attribute `data-already-active` is not `0` or `1` nor `true` or `false` but is the name of the attribute itself:

```
data-already-active="data-already-active"
```

Is this normal? Have I a better way of setting this information in the `checkbox`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yep, that seems to be the normal behavior for assigning **boolean** values for the twig attrs values. An easy workaround would be to modify the code a bit:

```
{{ form_widget(form.plan.seo, {'attr': {'class': 'feature', 'data-already-active': store.premium.hasSeo ? "1" : "0"}}) }}
```

or if you want to have this working with your current twig definition you can also move this boolean to string logic into the form template.

Comment: I think the use of a ternary op is the easiest and most practice one in this use case. Thank you!